# When using the rectangular marquee tool, are there guides to show the center while selecting?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When selecting something with the rectangular marquee tool, I'd sometimes like to see where the horizontal and vertical center are.  Is it possible to turn on some kind of guide that shows center information, or at least some kind of grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, as far as I know, but you can start draining from the center you want while holding the [ALT] key

Comment: Would love to have guides so that I can use them to move the selection after making it, but this works too.

Comment: sure you still can do that ... after making your selection go to `Select > Transform selection`